# Django: Model max_char not restricting database

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [django model CharField: max_length does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478054/django-model-charfield-max-length-does-not-work)

I have the following model:

```
class Draft(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
```

I somehow managed to get the following entry in my database:

```
dfadfadfadsfadfasdfasdfadfadfasdfadfadfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdfasdfadfadsfasdf
```

In the program I use to look at my mysqlite3 database, it lists the field as:

```
title( varchar(30) )
```

How is this possible. Please comment if more information is needed, I'm not sure what to post as I have no idea what is allowing this.

Comment: How could you add such entry, through django DB interface or some direct sql?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478054/django-model-charfield-max-length-does-not-work

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not enforce the length of a `VARCHAR`. See http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9