# django doesn't check CharField length on objects.create

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

i'm using django 1.10 and try to make some models which including some simple choices, this is my models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Person(models.Model):
    Senior='A'
    Middle='B'
    Junior='C'
    class_person=[(Senior,'Senior'),(Middle,'Middle'),\
             (Junior,'Junior')]

    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    grade=models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=class_person,default=Junior)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s in %s' % (self.name,self.grade)

    def is_senior(self):
        return self.grade in (self.Senior,self.Middle)
```

now i try make some Person objects instance via shell, for example

```
Person.objects.create(name='John',grade='Another')
```

now i call

```
Person.objects.all()
```

and it returns

```
<QuerySet [<Person: John in Another>]>
```

My question why the Person grade atribute can create the 'Another' as i know that grade models has maximum length of 2. thank you for the explanation

Comment: Are  you sure your that, in the database, the tables' columns definitions are up-to-date with your model? If you played with the value of max_length (or added it) after creating the tables, I think you may see such a behavior.

Comment: Is @mimo said your sure you have applied all required migrations? Also what type of db are you using?

Comment: @mimo yes i'm sure i've applied all migrations before i create the person object instance and i check it twice before answerring your question by create another models

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev i'm using default database sqlite3

Comment: It shouldn't be possible because it applies constraint on db level https://github.com/django/django/blob/b29c6c96c738bd7250a408b079dd8a4d4657849a/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py#L95

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev i don't know why may be you can try it in yours, is this behavior also happends in you, please inform if you have try. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the output of ".schema your_model_tablename" from the sqlite prompt?

Comment: @mimo ok this is my sqlite query 
sqlite> .schema latihan3_person
CREATE TABLE "latihan3_person" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "grade" varchar(2) NOT NULL);
sqlite>

Comment: @mimo and this is also sqlite> select * from latihan3_person;
5|John|Another
sqlite>

Comment: @WiraBhakti I have tested your code (removing @python_2_unicode_compatible, since I am on Python 2), and I get a "value too long" error at the ``create(...)`` line. I am using Postgresql.

Comment: @mimo thanks for advice may be SardorbekImomaliev below explain this....

Answer (score 3):

This is how sqlite3 works. Id doesn't enforce length restrictions

https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q9

> SQLite does not enforce the length of a VARCHAR. You can declare a VARCHAR(10) and SQLite will be happy to store a 500-million character string there. And it will keep all 500-million characters intact. Your content is never truncated. SQLite understands the column type of "VARCHAR(N)" to be the same as "TEXT", regardless of the value of N.

If you want more feature complete DB use postgres or mysql

Comment: @WiraBhakti it is not "maybe" it actually is. I got this quote directly from official docs. Read link in my answer

Comment: Sardorbek Imomaliev sorry cause i come from different langguage, English is not preferred langguage in my country so i very rare talking in english. greeting from Indonesia

Comment: @WiraBhakti understood. Greetings from Russia)) Also if this did answer your question you can accept by pressing button under votes. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -1):

Scrap my previous answer - 
According to 
[django model CharField: max_length does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478054/django-model-charfield-max-length-does-not-work)

SQLite does not enforce the max_length attribute.

As for input an invalid choice, it might possibly an issue with Django 1.10 (don't take my word for this part).

Comment: With Django 1.10, I get an error when trying to save an instance with a CharField with longer value than max_length: "value too long for type character varying(2)". Also your answer does not explain why Wira can print "<QuerySet [<Person: John in Another>]>" if the field can only hosts 2 characters.